# How store someone userid in my friends collection and How retrieve data of that user using firestore with flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store my friend userid in my friends collection.

I don't know how store someone details in other user collection.

Here is my code to get the currentUser.

```
  Future<void> _getUserDoc() async {
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;

    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    setState(() {
      userRef = _firestore.collection('users').document(user.uid);
    });
  }
```

**Database Structure**

```
USERS
-user1 (current user)
-name: John
-age: 20
--FRIENDS
----user2id
----user3id

-user2
-name: Richie
-age: 20
--FRIENDS
----user3id
```

This question has two parts-
1) How to store user2id and user3id in user1 FRIENDS collection.
2) How retrieve user2 data fields and shows in a widget.

Here is my Widget code, where I want to show *name* of user2.

```
   Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 10.0),
                    child: Text(
                      '20',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 17.0),
                    ),
                  ),
```

I want to show instead of *20* in Text widget, user2 age from firestore.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I think store the other user DocumentReference's, if you store other users `DocumentReference` in your current user you can build them with `FutureBuilder`

[image]

inside the red box : friends is Array of other User `DocumentReference`s

For Example you have User Model

```
class UserModel {
  final int age;
  final String name;
  final List<DocumentReference> friends;

  UserModel(this.age, this.name, this.friends);

  // to get from Firestore
  UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot):
    age = snapshot['age'],
    name = snapshot['name'],
    friends = List.from(snapshot['friends']);

}
```

and I'm assume you get the current user from firestore

`UserModel currentUser;`

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: currentUser.friends.first.get(), // this will take the first friend of current user
        // or you can query the list here with where 
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
              return Center(child: Text('Connection State none'));
            case ConnectionState.active:
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasError)
                return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
              return Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 10.0),
                    child: Text(
                      snapshot.data['age'],
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 17.0),
                    ),
                  );
          }
        });
```

I hope this will handle your problem.

Comment: Unable to store user2id

Comment: Can you give more information ? Post the code  where youre trying to store user2id ?